# How to specify raw html place in asciidoc?

Tags: asciidoc

I am trying to use raw html in asciidoc. To do that, I am using this;

```
+++<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@{/images/favicon.png}">+++
```

But this solution doesn't put the link tag inside the head tag. How can I specify it to put link tag inside the head tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach for modifying content within the `<head>` of an Asciidoctor-generated HTML page is to use docinfo files:

https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file

For example, in your Asciidoc document:

```
= My document title
:docinfo: shared

Lorem ipsum etc...
```

Then, create a file called `docinfo.html` in the same folder that contains your Asciidoc file, and define your `<link>` tags, additional CSS, etc. For example:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png">

<style>
// styles...
</style>
```